# Older Jamis Boss Cruisers

Tags: identify-this-bike

What year were these bikes made? Any idea of the value?[image]

Comment: We don't do valuations.  A steel bike of 15 kilograms is about $2 in aluminium, 50c in brass, and 5-20 cents in steel once you disassemble it all.  Plus some kilos of plastic and rubber, dirt and oil which have no direct value.   They look like 90s MTBs with cruiser handlebars and pool noodles fitted as grips.  Possibly the front chainring used to be a triple, if the bikes were designed as cruisers based on a MTB frame design.    Funky cupholders too.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a serial number on the bike somewhere, not sure where Jamis stamped there's but it is generally on the bottom bracket when the crank is.

On a total guess i would say mid 90s but again that is a guess based on looking at similar models and comparing decals and head badges. The 80's models had a metal head badge rather than these which looks to be a decal. The top and bottom tube decals were also more understated on the 80's models.

Pricing we don't really do on this website but i can tell you they were never super expensive bikes. If you can properly date it and find out what components are original it may fetch more. You may be able to contact Jamis with the serial number and find out more about it.

Jamis does however still make the Boss and the brand new models carry an MSRP of $399, i would imagine these two would sell for considerably less than that though as they are not exactly a collectors item that i am aware of like some 90s bikes.

You may find this page of interest, this is for a '99.
[Bicycle Blue Book 1999 Jamis Boss Cruiser](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/SearchListingDetail.aspx?id=83758&make=690&model=49482)

Comment: I would place it early 1990's, but mid 90's 1 1/8 steerer was typical.